# std::cin.ignore() ждёт ещё один символ

Tags: c++, консоль

`std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` ждёт ещё один символ при вводе через `std::cin` **числа**, а когда до этого была введена **буква**, он просто переходит к следующей строке кода.

Вот пример:
При вводе "t" или любого другого литерала выводится сразу "!!!" , а если это число (не 1 и не 2), то ожидается какой-то ещё ввод.

```
    int main()
{
    int solution;
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin >> solution;
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    if (solution == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "correct input 1." << std::endl;
    }
    else if (solution == 2)
    {
        std::cout << "correct input 2." << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Incorrect input, please enter only 1 or 2." << std::endl;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cout << "!!!" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Как сделать так, чтобы при вводе числа был осуществлён переход к новой строке сразу?**

Comment: Ничего не понял. Что такое `var`?

Comment: @AnT сейчас дополню описание

Comment: Если это `int var;`, то почему у вас в первом случае "был отправлен символ "t" с клавиатуры и **считан**". В такой ситуации символ `t` как раз таки **не** будет считан.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю так:

```
int var;
std::cin >> var; // был отправлен символ "t" с клавиатуры и считан
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
// переход к следующей строке кода
```

Тут у вас ошибка, символ остался непрочитанным, поток в состоянии ошибки, так что вы его сбросили верно.

```
int var;
std::cin >> var; // был отправлен символ "7" с клавиатуры и считан
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
// ожидание нового символа
```

Тут поток честно считал все, и сбрасывать хорошее состояние незачем. Лучше так:

```
if (!std::cin >> var) std::cin.clear();
```

Но вот только у меня оба **ваши** варианта на Visual C++ работают одинаково, ничего не ожидая

```
int var;
std::cin >> var;
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
std::cout << "!!!\n";
```

и сразу выводя `!!!`, что бы я ни ввел - t или 7. Может, вы не нажимаете Enter или показали не весь код?

Comment: Код полный, Enter нажимаю, пользуюсь Visual Studio 17

Comment: Я тоже, и никакого такого не наблюдаю. Нижний код - в main. Запускаю программу, `t Enter` - выводит `!!!`, заканчивается. Запускаю программу, `7 Enter` - выводит `!!!`, заканчивается. Что-то вы делаете не так, как я. О чем вы не пишете?

Comment: @Mikahio действительно, чего-то я не дописал. Дополнил вопрос.